# How do you force Android browser to use spinner instead of calendar when picking a date?

Tags: android, html

We have an HTML page where a date of birth is entered.  On most android devices, when you focus this field, the native android date spinner control opens.  However, on some android devices, the calendar view shows up instead.
The calendar view makes it very difficult to select a date of birth, as you can only navigate by months and not years.

So is there a way to force the calendar view to not be used?

Comment: FYI: You can navigate by years if you tab on the year in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the choice of the browser to show a calendar widget instead of a spinner. Because of this, you cannot choose what it opens in your website. One possible solution is to build your own date selector on the web page and then open it up when you need it. Most browsers nowaday have switched to a spinner. If a user is frustrated that they have to click back a whole bunch on a calendar, they need to switch to a newer browser.